# i am trying to extract youtube url in exoplayer. and i want to extract my sparsarray value in log

Tags: java, android

in log i want to see the structure of the array and also each index value of array in log. in log i print my arrays value in string. but i want to print each value of index individually using loop

```
  private void extractYoutubeUrl() {
        new YouTubeExtractor(this) {
            @Override
            public void onExtractionComplete(SparseArray<YtFile> ytFiles, VideoMeta vMeta) {
                //Log.d("======>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>", "onExtractionComplete: "+ytFiles.toString());



                Object object = ytFiles.toString();
                Log.d("=====>>>>>", "onExtractionComplete: "+object);
                if (ytFiles != null) {


                    playVideo(ytFiles.get(18).getUrl());


                }
            }
        }.extract(youtubeLink, true, true);
    }

    private void playVideo(String downloadUrl) {
        SimpleExoPlayerView simpleExoPlayer = findViewById(R.id.player);
        simpleExoPlayer.setPlayer(Exoplayer.getSharedInstance(MainActivity.this).getSimpleExoPlayerView().getPlayer());
        Exoplayer.getSharedInstance(MainActivity.this).playStream(downloadUrl);
    }
```

The error message is as follows:

```
D/=====>>>>>: onExtractionComplete: {18=YtFile{format=Format{itag=18, ext='mp4', height=360, fps=30, vCodec=null, aCodec=null, audioBitrate=96, isDashContainer=false, isHlsContent=false}, url='https://r4---sn-f5uxxo23-aixe.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1561567741&ei=nU0TXeK8MM79VvqnqYAG&ip=110.38.2.71&id=o-AFV33_psST4VR5T0XBSSnYFF4NYwTXtmVU9b9JNOntHM&itag=18&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mm=31%2C29&mn=sn-f5uxxo23-aixe%2Csn-ug5onfvgaq-3ipl&ms=au%2Crdu&mv=m&pl=23&initcwndbps=111250&mime=video%2Fmp4&gir=yes&clen=939591692&ratebypass=yes&dur=13222.138&lmt=1532605335975188&mt=1561545988&fvip=1&c=WEB&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Citag%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cmime%2Cgir%2Cclen%2Cratebypass%2Cdur%2Clmt&sig=ALgxI2wwRAIgTIKHyf6th_MgaMMMHrNKrm1j7xo__qxW-wS_60z1rVwCIFqvDjeC-aHPrlQchpGb7UB25DvTw46d5E-18ydQhDjD&lsparams=mm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cpl%2Cinitcwndbps&lsig=AHylml4wRAIgY8a7JD5ye84PLBOTVZQicZzcDE3fBCK09Qd3P2BLq9QCIBwCIqKqT0raHNYn2DuEPGq8W9Oosb7jHDgI31cJAYCp'}, 22=YtFile{format=Format{itag=22, ext='mp4', height=720, fps=30, vCodec=null, aCodec=null, audioBitrate=192, isDashContainer=false, isHlsContent=false}, url='https://r4---sn-f5uxxo23-aixe.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1561567741&ei=nU0TXeK8MM79VvqnqYAG&ip=110.38.2.71&id=o-AFV33_psST4VR5T0XBSSnYFF4NYwTXtmVU9b9JNOntHM&itag=22&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mm=31%2C29&mn=sn-f5uxxo23-aixe%2Csn-ug5onfvgaq-3ipl&ms=au%2Crdu&mv=m&pl=23&initcwndbps=111250&mime=video%2Fmp4&ratebypass=yes&dur=13222.138&lmt=1532618663945965&mt=1561545988&fvip=1&c=WEB&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Citag%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cmime%2Cratebypass%2Cdur%2Clmt&sig=ALgxI2wwRgIhALfvZziguzUYvX6D9HfEk08b4iUCoJsZtfFhRuq9pQ-LAiEAkzCzEDb3f9pddacZxkzWZ6hcsUQyKPsEklxWz2Wtl38%3D&lsparams=mm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cpl%2Cinitcwndbps&lsig=AHylml4wRAIgY8a7JD5ye84PLBOTVZQicZzcDE3fBCK09Qd3P2BLq9QCIBwCIqKqT0raHNYn2DuEPGq8W9Oosb7jHDgI31cJAYCp'}, 43=YtFile{format=Format{itag=43, ext='webm', height=360, fps=30, vCodec=null, aCodec=null, audioBitrate=128, isDashContainer=false, isHlsContent=false}, url='https://r4---sn-f5uxxo23-aixe.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1561567741&ei=nU0TXeK8MM79VvqnqYAG&ip=110.38.2.71&id=o-AFV33_psST4VR5T0XBSSnYFF4NYwTXtmVU9b9JNOntHM&itag=43&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mm=31%2C29&mn=sn-f5uxxo23-aixe%2Csn-ug5onfvgaq-3ipl&ms=au%2Crdu&mv=m&pl=23&initcwndbps=111250&mime=video%2Fwebm&gir=yes&clen=1109252495&ratebypass=yes&dur=0.000&lmt=1545681670086031&mt=1561545988&fvip=1&c=WEB&txp=5511222&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Citag%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cmime%2Cgir%2Cclen%2Cratebypass%2Cdur%2Clmt&sig=ALgxI2wwRAIgGfLjsVL8LfHTkb5NrFQCPpDj0eFJLpmVSlSOq7u0h0UCIFH-oZA_XLSqA2itI3KRmlnVwCg1CFSrD05jWA9UKBPX&lsparams=mm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cpl%2Cinitcwndbps&lsig=AHylml4wRAIgY8a7JD5ye84PLBOTVZQicZzcDE3fBCK09Qd3P2BLq9QCIBwCIqKqT0raHNYn2DuEPGq8W9Oosb7jHDgI31cJAYCp'}, 133=YtFile{format=Format{itag=133, ext='mp4', height=240, fps=30, vCodec=null, aCodec=null, audioBitrate=-1, isDashContainer=true, isHlsContent=false}, url='https://r4---sn-f5uxxo23-aixe.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1561567741&ei=nU0TXeK8MM79VvqnqYAG&ip=110.38.2.71&id=o-AFV33_psST4VR5T0XBSSnYFF4NYwTXtmVU9b9JNOntHM&itag=133&aitags=133%2C134%2C135%2C136%2C137%2C160%2C242%2C243%2C244%2C247%2C248%2C271%2C278%2C313&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mm=31%2C29&mn=sn-f5uxxo23-aixe%2Csn-ug5onfvgaq-3ipl&ms=au%2Crdu&mv=m&pl=23&initcwndbps=111250&mime=video%2Fmp4&gir=yes&clen=248267610&dur=13222.073&lmt=1532609281418272&mt=1561545988&fvip=1&keepalive=yes&c=WEB&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Caitags%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cmime%2Cgir%2Cclen%2Cdur%2Clmt&sig=ALgxI2wwRQIgGfg93vtkMq3DL_pqMWqIGFvpM0LXfOf-SYmJDTpw4MACIQDiiKhIMEDTFlkryVhiIwah65Aph8OwwjdHQRpFzKzeUA%3D%3D&lsparams=mm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cpl%2Cinitcwndbps&lsig=AHylml4wRAIgY8a7JD5ye84PLBOTVZQicZzcDE3fBCK09Qd3P2BLq9QCIBwCIqKqT0raHNYn2DuEPGq8W9Oosb7jHDgI31cJAYCp'}, 134=YtFile{format=Format{itag=134, ext='mp4', height=360, fps=30, vCodec=null, aCodec=null, audioBitrate=-1, isDashContainer=true, isHlsContent=false}, url='https://r4---sn-f5uxxo23-aixe.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?e
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly this will do the trick:

```
for(i=0, size = ytFiles.size(); i < size; i++){
    YtFile ytFile = ytFiles.valueAt(i);
    Log.d(TAG, "index: " + i + " path: " + ytFile.getUrl);
    }
```